# Decision tree vs linear SVM

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, cart

Is it correct to say that, a difference between decision trees and linear SVMs is that the hyperplanes used by the decision trees are perpendicular to axis?

Comment: Is this question homework? Consider the tag [tag:self-study], and read its description and wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant the independent variables (features) axes, the phrasing is a bit off. The SVM (linear or otherwise) uses a single decision hyperplane. The decision trees, however, are not bound to a single hyperplane: they use multiple decision rules. Some tree architectures use oblique decisions as well.

An ordinary stump (one-level decision tree) uses a single hyperplane (like a SVM) orthogonal to a feature.

Comment: They also learn the hyperplanes by very different means, and the hyperplanes in a tree are NOT necessarily decision boundaries.